# My cat repeated uses his litter box when I clean it

Tags: cats, defecation

When I get up or get home from work I clean my cat's litter box. He then goes on it immediately, so I clean it again. The cycle repeats a few times before he runs out of pee.

It's only started in the last few months. How can I stop him doing this? Is he having trouble emptying his bladder?

Comment: just to get a clearer understanding of this,is it like your cat are using the litterbox only when you clean it,or is it that your cat uses the litterbox more when you clean it.when your cat uses the litterbox outside the time you clean it like at night does he pee a little and often or does he pee like normal a couple of times during the night? what happens if you clean the litterbox only once and leave it to the next day?

Comment: I'm not sure what he does at night. I think he goes just once. Then five times in the morning, waiting for me to clean it each time.

Comment: if your cat only goes once or twice in 12 hours it is unlikely to be a medical problem,and you do not need to clean the litterbox more than once even if he pee right after you have cleaned the litterbox.cleaning the litterbox a couple of times a day is fine.

Answer (score 2):

It could be that he has some UTI or kidney stones, so you should get him checked by vet, just in case. It would be ideal if you could collect some pee, because that helps the vet check for urinary stones. (My own cat often pees in the carrier from excitement, so I don't put any absorbent material in when we go to the vet.)

Cats cannot tell you if they feel pain when urinating. So instead they show you the problem by urinating in very obvious and often inappropriate places.

Especially male cats are very predisposed for urinary stones. If it turns out that he has a problem, you should consider switching to cat food with low grain content or special food to avoid urinary stones.